# how implements INotifyPropertyChanged to make Observablecollection notify that elements changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a view model that presents items in ListBox. There are two collection: `Source` contains all element and `Checked` contains only checked elements. There are two buttons SelectAll and ClearAll. When I push on one of this button View Model works well and both `Source` and `Checked` collections updating, but no changes in Listbox happens.

`CheckItemPresenterVM<T>` - an element that save the state of one button and implements INotifyPropertyChange, but when property `IsChecked` changes `CollectionChanged`event doesn't reise.

The question is how to make it work?

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="listPanelTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>


    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemIsCheckedBinding"
           TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="5,3" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="LightCyan"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="7, 3" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="7, 3" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="1" />
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Expander Header="Categories"
              IsExpanded="True">

        <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0"
                       Margin="0, 5">
                <Button Command="{Binding SelectAll}">Select All</Button>
                <Button Command="{Binding ClearAll}">Clear All</Button>
                <Button Command="{Binding InvertSelection}">Invert Selection</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" />
            <ListBox Name="CategoriesListBox"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryVM.Source, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemIsCheckedBinding}"
                     ItemsPanel="{StaticResource listPanelTemplate}" />
            <ListBox Name="CheckedListBox"
                     Grid.Row="3"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryVM.Checked}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

```
class TestViewModel
{
    public CheckItemVM<string> CategoryVM { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        logger.FileName = "TestSelectionFilter.txt";
        logger.AddEventRecord(this);

        CategoryVM = new CheckItemVM<string>(
            new List<string>() {
                "01 elem",
                "02 elem",
                "03 elem",
                "04 elem",
                "05 elem",
                "06 elem",
                "07 elem",
                "08 elem",
                "09 elem",
                "10 elem",
                "11 elem",
                "12 elem",
                "13 elem",
                "14 elem",
                "15 elem",
                "16 elem",
                "17 elem",
                "18 elem",
                "19 elem",
                "20 elem",
                "21 elem",
                "22 elem",
                "23 elem",
                "24 elem",
                "25 elem"});
    }

    public ICommand SelectAll
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand
            {
                ExecuteAction = a =>
                {
                    CategoryVM.SelectAll();
                },
                CanExecutePredicate = p =>
                {
                    return !CategoryVM.IsAllSelected();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand InvertSelection
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand
            {
                ExecuteAction = a =>
                {
                    CategoryVM.InvertSelection();
                },
                CanExecutePredicate = p =>
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand ClearAll
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand
            {
                ExecuteAction = a =>
                {
                    CategoryVM.ClearAll();
                },
                CanExecutePredicate = p =>
                {
                    return CategoryVM.Checked.Any();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

---

```
class CheckItemVM<T>
{

    protected ObservableCollection<CheckItemPresenterVM<T>> _checked = new ObservableCollection<CheckItemPresenterVM<T>>();

    public ObservableCollection<CheckItemPresenterVM<T>> Source { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CheckItemPresenterVM<T>> Checked { get => _checked; }

    public CheckItemVM(ICollection<T> _source)
    {
        Source = new ObservableCollection<CheckItemPresenterVM<T>>();
        UpdateSource(_source);
    }


    protected void UpdateSource(ICollection<T> _source)
    {
        foreach (var item in _source)
        {
            Source.Add(new CheckItemPresenterVM<T>(ref _checked)
            { Item = item, IsChecked = false });
        }
    }

    public void SetSelection(CheckItemPresenterVM<T> sourceItem, bool flag)
    {
        if (sourceItem.IsChecked != flag)
        {
            sourceItem.IsChecked = flag;
        }
    }

    public void SelectAll()
    {
        foreach (var item in Source)
        {
            item.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }

    public void ClearAll()
    {
        foreach (var item in Source)
        {
            item.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }

    public void InvertSelection()
    {
        foreach (var item in Source)
        {
            if (item.IsChecked) item.IsChecked = false;
            else item.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsAllSelected()
    {
        return Source.Count == Checked.Count;
    }
}


class CheckItemPresenterVM<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool _isChecked;
    protected ObservableCollection<CheckItemPresenterVM<T>> _checked;

    public CheckItemPresenterVM(ref ObservableCollection<CheckItemPresenterVM<T>> Checked)
    {
        _checked = Checked;
    }

    public T Item { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            if (value)
            {
                if (!_checked.Contains(this))
                {
                    _checked.Add(this);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Item was Checked");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_checked.Contains(this))
                {
                    _checked.Remove(this);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Item Unchecked");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Item.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you would need two collections. One collection with an element type that has a (notifying) IsChecked property should be sufficient. Bind both ListBoxes to the same collection. In the ItemContainerStyle of the "checked only" ListBox, set the ListBoxItem Visibility by a DataTrigger on the IsChecked property.

Comment: Why would the CollectionChanged event be raised when IsChecked is set? Please clarify your issue. How to reproduce your issue?

Comment: The problem is: Even if i have only one collection '''Source''' I need the PropertyChanged event reise when IsChecked change. In my solution it is not happen and I can t understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see strange part of you code.
Guessing this fix in `PropertyChanged` raising call

```cs
public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            if (value)
            {
                if (!_checked.Contains(this))
                {
                    _checked.Add(this);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_checked.Contains(this))
                {
                    _checked.Remove(this);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`NotifyPropertyChanged` fires `PoropertyChanged` Event with a string parameter you passing to. Meanwhile `Binding` will receive it.

**So, here's 2 friends**

```xml
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and

```cs
NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
```

If you need tune the update behavior of your control, pass `UpdateSourceTrigger` setting to to the binding, this way:

```xml
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Additionally: `TwoWay` is default for the `Mode` here. You may not declare it.

Answer (score 0):

When binding a View/Control to an ObservableCollection the View/Control will be redrawn when the CollectionChanged event of ObservableCollection is raised.

This occurs when an item is added, removed, reordered or assigned a new instance; but not (as you've probably realised) when an item raises it's PropertyChanged event.

To get your changes to be reflected in the UI you need the PropertyChanged of each Item to raise the CollectionChanged event of the collection.

```
public class ObservableItemCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Call this from the constructor
    private void InitialiseItems()
    {
        CollectionChanged += ContentCollectionChanged;

        foreach (T item in Items)
            item.PropertyChanged += ReplaceElementWithItself;
    }

    private void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= ReplaceElementWithItself;
            }
        }

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += ReplaceElementWithItself;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReplaceElementWithItself(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var collectionChangedArgs = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, sender, sender, IndexOf((T)sender));

        // Call this on the main thread
        OnCollectionChanged(collectionChangedArgs);
    }
}
```

This implementation simply raises the CollectionChanged event as a 'Replace' where the same Item is both removed and inserted, at the same index. Beware that it could have unintended consequences if you have anything that actually cares about the CollectionChanged events beyond binding it to the UI; but it is the simplest way I have found to achieve what you are after.